# Overwrote old table with transient table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When trying to create a transient table in the process over creating an scd2, I overwrote the original table, as I named the transient table the same name as the original table. Is there anyway I can solve this? This would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you open a support ticket, I believe that transient tables do not have a retention https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#time-travel-notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on exactly what you've done, but this might work.

```
alter table my_table rename to my_table_temp
undrop table my_table
```

You can rename the transient table, then undrop the table. The undrop command finds the last time a table was dropped with that name (which includes when a `create or replace` command was run)

You can also try using time travel if you have that set up correctly. Documentation on that [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-time-travel.html#understanding-using-time-travel).